# For-loop in another for-loop VHDL

Tags: for-loop, generator, vhdl, synthesis

The output of a specific entity depends on it's own location in the vector and all inputs. The easiest way to implement this seems to be a for-loop in a for-loop. However, Quartus II 13.0sp1 fails on the second for-loop:

```
VHDL syntax error at mcve.vhd(24) near text "IN"; expecting "(", or "'", or "."
```

I might have messed up the syntax, but I'm sure VHDL is capable of looping in a loop.

What's the correct implementation of a for-loop in a for-loop? Here is what I've got so far.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

TYPE ANAT_SLV16 IS ARRAY ( NATURAL RANGE <> ) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 15 DOWNTO 0 );

ENTITY mcve IS
    GENERIC(
        PORTS  : POSITIVE := 256;
        HPORTS : POSITIVE := 128
    );
PORT(
    X : IN  ANAT_SLV16( PORTS - 1 DOWNTO 0 );
    Y : OUT ANAT_SLV16( HPORTS - 1 DOWNTO 0 );
    );
END mcve;

ARCHITECTURE loops OF mcve IS
    SIGNAL to_Y : ANAT_SLV16( HPORTS - 1 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others -> '0');
BEGIN

    gen : FOR i IN 0 TO HPORTS - 1 GENERATE
        FOR j IN 0 TO PORTS - 1 GENERATE -- error near text "IN"; expecting "(", or "'", or "."
            to_Y(( i )) <= to_Y(( i )) + X( j );
        END GENERATE;
    END GENERATE;

    Y <= to_Y;

END loops;
```

Comment: Don't you should give a label to the second loop ?

Comment: The type declaration should be in a package visible by a use clause. There's an extra semicolon in the port clause at the end of the `y` port declaration. `->` should be `=>` and the default expression should be `(others =>(others => '0'))` - `to_y` is an array of std_logic_vector. To have both bounds of ranges the same base type those generics should be `natural`'s (right bounds 0). To use the `"+"`operator from package numeric_std the operands need to be type converted to unsigned, the result to std_logic_vector. Then the MVCe is complete and verifiable and fixable with Brian's label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't FOR loops. They are FOR..GENERATE statements, and each needs its own label.

```
gen : FOR i IN 0 TO HPORTS - 1 GENERATE
    gen2: FOR j IN 0 TO PORTS - 1 GENERATE
        to_Y(( i )) <= to_Y(( i )) + X( j );
    END GENERATE;
END GENERATE;
```

I hope you have a good feel for the size of the hardware this will generate.

Comment: Although this will fix your syntax error, your design still won't work. `to_Y(( i )) <= to_Y(( i )) + X( j );` will create a combinatorial loop (and multiple assignment errors for `to_Y(i)`) because it is not within a clocked process. If you switch to for loops inside of a clocked process, your inner loop won't do anything because only the last assignment of `to_Y(i) <= to_Y(i) + X(PORTS-1);` will take effect for each `i` because to_Y is a signal. This is one of those rare instances where I would suggest the use of a variable to a beginner.

Comment: Also, "thousands of LE's" is an understatement by about two orders of magnitude. If implemented with the apparently intended functionality and the default `PORTS` and `HPORTS` values, there will be about 16k ternary 16-bit adders (more efficient with modern LUT6s than dual adders) which will consume about 250k LUT6s. The smallest 7-series FPGA with 250k+ LUTs is a 7k410t, which is an absolutely huge FPGA for such simple logic. If you're just trying to do a proof-of-concept in simulation this is fine, but if you want to do a physical prototype you will have to do **some** optimization first.